# Plotting only 1 arrow in loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a series of wind directions depicted by an arrow with a certain size dependant of the strength of the wind. But all I can do in my loop is plot one arrow over the other one. I only want one arrow per plot.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's my code, moving the ax = plt.axes() out of the loop does not help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import math

Dir2013 =np.loadtxt('H:/EMBC/Thesis/Data/Wind/winddir_2013_Westhinder.txt') #wind direction
Vel2013 =np.loadtxt('H:/EMBC/Thesis/Data/Wind/windvel_2013_Westhinder.txt') #wind velocity
Start=[]
Stop=[]
kl=[]
kl2=[]
for i in range (0, len(Dir2013)):
    if Dir2013[i][5]==39:
        Start=i
    if Dir2013[i][5]==154:
        Stop=i  
    if Vel2013[i][6]<0:
        Vel2013[i][6]==0
        kl.append(i)
        kl2.append(Vel2013[i][6])

parts=(len(Dir2013)/365)
Steps=(Stop-Start)/parts

for i in range (Start, Stop,int(parts)): 
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.set_xlim(left=-3, right=3, emit=True, auto=False)
    ax.set_ylim(bottom=-3, top=3, emit=True, auto=False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('k')
    ax.spines['top'].set_color('k')
    ax.spines['left'].set_color('k')
    ax.spines['right'].set_color('k')
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='k')
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='k')
    x0, y0 = 0, 0
    radius = Vel2013[i][6]*0.1
    angle_rad = int(Dir2013[i][6])* math.pi / 180  # degrees to radians
    head_length = 0.08
    ax.arrow(x0, y0,
   (radius - head_length) * math.cos(angle_rad),
   (radius - head_length) * math.sin(angle_rad),
   head_width=0.08, head_length=head_length, fc='k', ec='k',width=0.01)
    plt.savefig('ArrowAa%d' %i)
plt.show()
```

**How do I plot only one arrow per plot?**

Comment: have you tried setting a figure before `ax = plt.axes()` (ie `plt.figure()`) ? (not sure at all)

Comment: @bobrobbob that was it! thanx!